# in asp.net core Component @OnClick not trigger target method

Tags: asp.net-core, onclick, components, razor-pages

I try to use my repository data to display in card view, then press button to see more information about the item, it does not work. @OnClick is only working for JSON data
`@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` - to access `@onclick` and more option

`repoItem` - my ItemRepository for get data from database
`@OnClick="(e => SelectProduct(item.Id))"` - when i click item card, its shoud get item id send to `SelectProduct(item.Id)` method.

but it work for following link. he works with JSON data but I need to work for model data.

https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/ContosoCrafts/blob/master/src/Components/ProductList.razor

```
<div class="card-columns">
@foreach (var item in repoItem.GetAll())
{
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
<h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title"> Total available items : @item.Quantity</h5>
<h5 class="card-title">Price : Rs. @item.Price.00</h5>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
<small class="text-muted">
<button @onclick="(e => SelectProduct(item.Id))"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" class="btn btn-primary">
More Info
</button>
</small>
</div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

```
@code {

Item selectedItem;
int selectedItemId;


void SelectProduct(int productId)
{
    selectedItemId = productId;
    selectedItem = _context.Items.Where(x => x.Id == selectedItemId).FirstOrDefault();
    ContItem();
}

int itemcnt = 0;
string cuntLable;
void ContItem()
{
    if (selectedItem.Quantity != null || selectedItem.Quantity != 0)
    {
        itemcnt = selectedItem.Quantity;
        cuntLable = itemcnt.ToString();
    }
    else cuntLable = "Not available ..!";
}
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure right now, but have you tried a lower-case `@onclick="…"`? I think it is case-sensitive. That being said, what exactly is not working? Is your `SelectProduct` method being called at all? Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: @poke actually I used `@onclick="…" `it's modified when I try to copy my code here. `@onclick`  will suggest by intellisense `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` this library have `on` options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem: `@onclick`=".." is not hit my `selectprodect` method breakpoint when clicking the button.

Solution: the mistake is `Statup.cs` need to add `services.AddServerSideBlazor()` in `ConfigureServices` and then add in `Configure` part `endpoints.MapBlazorHub()`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            });
```

after 6 hours of hard work. @onclick is worked smoothly